# Chart line jumping instead interpolating correctly

Tags: reactjs, charts, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm using AMCharts 4 and I am passing hour - values data pairs. So for example at 15h there is value of 10, at 16h value of 15, etc.

```
[...{
    "date": new Date(2020, 1, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0),
    "value": 10,
}, {
    "date": new Date(2020, 1, 1, 16, 0, 0, 0),
    "value": 15,
}...]
```

Chart is not plotting lines between points correctly (it is displaying correct data, but line is not printed as it should).

Example:

[image]

As you can see in the example above, it is displaying correct data but it does not have correct interpolation between lines. From example from picture it is obvious that from 14h to 15h it is a uptrend and that line should go up gradually and be there for 15h. Instead, it gradually goes down and when it realizes the value for 15h it moves up instantly to correct it.

I tried `series.sequencedInterpolation = true` but it does not have any effect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After so much time wasted on this, I figured it out.

DateAxis has `baseInterval` which is calculated automatically if not set manually. Obviously it did not calculate it correctly and it was glitching out. By setting it to following settings it worked:

```
xAxes1.baseInterval = [
    { timeUnit: "hour", count: 1 },
...];
```

In the array you can specify for each time unit the count that you have.

Docs: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/dateaxis/